# How to reduce a constrained Non-Linear Optimization problem to a unconstrained?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following non-linear optimization problem:

$$ (NLO) \ \ \ min \ \ \ \ x_3^2 - x_4 $$
$$ s.t. \ \ x_2+x_3 = 1$$
$$ x_1^2+x_4 = 1$$

How can this be reduced to be an unconstrained optimization problem?

No I haven't. The only knowledge I have on the subject is from a complicated math text, I am way over my head. From what I understand $$ Ax = b = Bx_B + Nx_N $$ where B and N are partitions of A as $ A=[B,N]$ and x is partitioned $x^T = [x_B, x_N]^T$ I have no idea what partitions are, or how we determine which $ x_n $ are in which partition, and what values of A are in which partition. We can somehow use the above equality and sub it into the original function but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Have you heard of Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: No I haven't. The only knowledge I have on the subject is from a complicated math text, I am way over my head. From what I understand $$ Ax = b = Bx_b + Nx_N $$ where B and N are partitions of A as $ A=[B,N]$ and x is partitioned $x^T = [x_B, x_N]^T$ I have no idea what partitions are, or how we determine which $ x_n $ are in which partition, and what values of A are in which partition. We can somehow use the above equality and sub it into the original function but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can do substitutions to eliminate the constraints here.

Comment: Am I overthinking it then? Would the unconstrained problem just be $$ (1-x_2)^2 - (1-x_1^2) $$ ? substituting $x_4 = 1-x_1^2$ and $x_3 = 1-x_2$ into the objective function?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2028481/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66393/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: Apologizes, I just thought it was more of a CS question, but then someone immediately commented on there "What does this have to do with CS", so I figured Mathematics was the better choice.